# How print Pearson correlation matrix to Word in r

Tags: r, export, correlation

I'm quite new to R and I want to plot a fancy correlation matrix in a word document.

here a little example of my data:

```
provaSO1 <- structure(list(TotalDebt = c(0.637, 0.517, 0.581, 0.785, 0.687,0.703, 0.474), 
               Long_ok = c(0.157, 0.121, 0.051, 0.29, 0.153,0.301, 0.102), 
               Short_ok = c(0.48, 0.396, 0.531, 0.495, 0.535,0.402, 0.372), 
               Size = c(6.184, 6.184, 6.663, 7.302, 6.714, 6.949,7.627), 
               ln_Age = c(3.638, 3.664, 3.689, 3.714, 3.738, 3.761, 3.784), 
               liquidity = c(0.99, 0.988, 0.995, 0.965, 0.949, 0.949,0.53),
               Asset_Tangibility = c(0.005, 0.006, 0.003, 0.023, 0.033, 0.03, 0.457), 
               profitability = c(-0.058, -0.202, -0.106, 0.032, 0.03, 0.013, 0.042)), 
          row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

first I want to calculate the correlation matrix:

```
c_matrix = cor(provaSO1, method = c("pearson"))
```

the I use `corstars function` to add significance level and gain only the lower triangle:

```
corstarsl <- function(x){
  require(Hmisc)
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  R <- rcorr(x)$r
  p <- rcorr(x)$P

 mystars <- ifelse(p < .001, "***", ifelse(p < .01, "** ", ifelse(p < .05, "* ", " ")))

 R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 3))[,-1]

 Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x))
  diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="")
  rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x)
  colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="")

 Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
  Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
  Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew)
 
  Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
  return(Rnew)
}
```

At the end I plot my table and export to excel:

```
matrix_correlation <- corstarsl(provaSO1)

library(xtable)
corr_print <- xtable(matrix_correlation)

library(rio) 
library(openxlsx)
export(corr_print,"correlation_ok.xlsx")
```

I want to know **if there are more elegant way for print the Pearson Correlation matrix and put in Word document** (eg. Stargazer for regression tables).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you could directly write by xlsx(to write excel) package. not sure there is some function directly for docx extension but after writing an excel sheet it would be way easier to move it to any other office file

Comment: Thanks @SametSökel, I think is difficult find what I'm looking for, hope someone know a way to print as 'stargazer' do in ".docx" or "html" for put directly to document, without further step.

Comment: if you are working on R Studio, you could directly export your notebooks as html pages. you can prefer printing in R , then knit your noteebok as html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`modelsummary` package for `R`](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) to save a correlation table directly to a Word document. (Disclaimer: I am the author.) Using the `datasummary_correlation` function and its `output` argument, we have:

```r
library(modelsummary)

datasummary_correlation(provaSO1,
                        output = "correlation_table.docx")
```